# Titanium Set system default unit different for App and Modules

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm utilizing the Ti.Barcode module in my Titanium App.

Once the Default Unit System was set to 'dp' the overlay of this module changed too.

Now some components are out of scale and is not possible change them via API.

So is there a method to keep the System Default Unit to 'dp' and change it only to that activity/module?

Thank you